# Fail to install R-4.1.0 to windows 10 even with admin right

Tags: r, installation

I have admin right to the desktop. But right off the bat, the installer gives me this warning:
[You should be logged in as an administrator when installing R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPKlm.png)

I created the R folders in Program Files, and still the installer claims it cannot create files. Does any of you have a solution for that?

Thank you.

Comment: If you right click on the installer, is there an option to "run as administrator"? The things it wants administrator privileges for aren't really required to use R. Is this your own machine or a work machine? If the latter you might want to ask your IT department what sort of restrictions might have been placed on it It's not easy to guess how machines might be locked down.

Comment: Yes, run as admin. It is a work computer, I have all the possible permissions to the Program Files folder.